# How to search in a column with more row a specific word?

Tags: php

Maybe my question was already answered before, but my mistake if I don't know the correct specific words to search for it.
So, I have this code

```
<?php
$adm = connect::$g_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admins` WHERE `access` LIKE '%t%' or `access` LIKE '%n%' ORDER by Admin DESC");
$adm->execute();
while($row = $adm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { ?>

<?php
        if($row->access == '%t%') echo ' <span class="badge" style="background-color:#CC9900"><strong>VIP GOLD</strong></span>';
        if($row->access == '%n%') echo ' <span class="badge" style="background-color:#6F7683"><strong>VIP SILVER</strong></span>';
?>
<?php } ?>
```

My problem is that in those 2 IFS. I have a column `admin` with more rows (around 20). My issue is that on first if i want to search in all of those 20 rows from `admins` column and if letter T is found to echo VIP GOLD
Same with the second if, but letter N. Anyway if I will figure it out with T, of course will be the same for the second.

Sorry again, if I don't explain it correctly, these are my first days into php. Not trying to learn big, but at least what I need.

If it helps, here is the code I want to make it work
https://ploiesti.csstats.eu/vips
On the grade column, to show GOLD or SILVER depending if those persons has T or N in the flags behind their names.

Many thank for the help.
Regards.

Comment: Look into https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: What you need is `strpos` function.

Comment: You are misusing prepared statements. You need to bind values. For your current question `strpos` or `preg_match` could be used. There aren't wildcards for PHP comparisons.

Comment: @Mihai in_array wont help here, need partial matching

Comment: Ok, obviously you know what I did wrong, but could you maybe please correct that? As I am not familiar at all...
strpos function shows me how to search and show on the page where it can be found the $search, but instead of that I want to show a defined word

Comment: Something like `if(strpos($row->access, 't') !== FALSE) { ...}`

Comment: Thank you @user3783243 it works :D happy for now.